F test to compare variances. How is ncp calculated to obtain the F distribution under the alt hypothesis?
Recently I needed to do a power analysis for a comparison of variance with a F test.
In the past I used the OC curves from Edwin Crow's "Statistics Manual" Chart VIII to get beta. https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/tr/pdf/AD0149334.pdf
For example lambda = sd1/sd2 = 3, n=7 both groups, indicates beta ~0.2 on the chart (power = 80%). text
Using the package pwrss:
power.f.test(ncp = 3, df1 = 6, df2 = 6, alpha = 0.05)




power
ncp.alt
ncp.null
alpha
df1
df2
f.crit




0.11191
3
0
0.05
6
6
4.2838



i.e beta ~0.89
presumably ncp for the alternative hypothesis is not sd1/sd2. var1/var2 would be 9:
power.f.test(ncp = 9, df1 = 6, df2 = 6, alpha = 0.05)




power
ncp.alt
ncp.null
alpha
df1
df2
f.crit




0.26454
9
0
0.05
6
6
4.2838



i.e. beta ~0.74
...so what is ncp in terms of the sd1 and sd2? I've used ncp in t-tests and Hotelling T2 tests, where the parameter is well documented, but I am only finding a few examples using ncp in the context of estimating power in anova calculations.
I did find this page: Stats Kingdom which appears to be a shiny app. Here the Ha appears to be df(x/(var1/var2), df1, df2) although the H0 pdf has area under the curve =1, the Ha (var1/var2) area under the curve is decidedly >1.
Thanks for any hints or directions to more documentation.
THere is this publication, although its a bit hard going. Ali Baharev, Hermann Schichl, and Endre Rév2, Computing the noncentral-F distribution and the power of the F-test with guaranteed accuracy. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7010373/

Greetings! Can you format your code so it is more readable? The output in particular is a bit cryptic and could use some clarification.

added some markdown to show output in a table.

The non-central $F$ distribution is the alternative-hypothesis distribution for ANOVA or regression, not for the test of equality of variances. That is, it is the distribution of the ratio of sums of squares of Normals when the variables in the numerator don't have mean zero.
When you have zero means but unequal variances, as in a test for equality of variances, the distribution of $s_1^2/s_2^2$ is a scaled central $F$. (In other words, you can't use power.f.test for it)

Duh . So F distributes as df(x/delta, n1-1, n2-1) under Ha where delta=Var1/Var2 != 1?

Yes, that's right

Here is some R script to show the test graphically:
# one sided test and checking power for a difference in variances (in this 
# case an assay sd at 0.53% was compared to a the laboratory requirement that
# was 5% RSD, mean was 54.06, so we are comparing sd1 0.53 against sd2 2.7)
# Parameters

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(latex2exp)

sd1<-0.53
sd2<-54.06*0.05
n1 <- 8
n2 <- 8

v1<-sd1^2
v2<-sd2^2
delta<-max(v1,v2)/min(v1,v2)
alpha <- 0.05

# find F where area of Ho is 0.05 on RH side
RH.crit <- qf((1-alpha),n1-1,n2-1)

# in this case RH.crit is 3.8 so our F statistic at 26 means we can 
# reject Null and checking beta is moot, but for completeness sake...

# then use this to find area on LH side of the Ha curve to get beta
beta<- pf(RH.crit/delta, n1-1, n2-1)

#make dataframe containing the Ho and Ha distributions
F<-seq(from = 0.01, to = 28, length = 1000)
Ho<-df(F, n1-1, n2-1)
Ha<-df(F/delta, n1-1, n2-1)
dd<-data.frame(F,Ho,Ha)

# mark out Ho rejection region so we can color the graph correctly
df<-dd %>%
  mutate(HoReject = 
           ifelse(pf(F,n1-1,n2-1 ) > 1-alpha, "Yes", "No" ))


#Plot
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_area(aes(x=F, y=Ho, fill=HoReject), alpha=0.4) +
  geom_area(aes(x=F, y=Ha, fill=HoReject), alpha=0.4) +
  annotate(geom="text", x = 2.5, y = 0.6, 
           label = TeX(r"($H_{0}=\frac{\sigma^2_a}{sigma^2_b}=1)", output = "character"), 
       parse = TRUE,
       size = 5, na.rm = TRUE)+
  annotate(geom="text", x = 15, y = 0.6, 
       label = TeX(r"($H_{a}=\frac{\sigma^2_a}{sigma^2_b}=26)", output = "character"), 
           parse = TRUE,
           size = 5, na.rm = TRUE)+
  annotate("segment", x = 10, xend = 5, y = 0.1, yend = 0.01, 
           linewidth=2, alpha=0.6, arrow=arrow())+
  annotate(geom="text", x = 10, y = 0.15, 
           label = TeX(r"($\alpha=0.05)", output = "character"), 
           parse = TRUE,
           size = 5, na.rm = TRUE)+
  annotate(geom="text", x = 3, y = 0.35,
           hjust=0,
           label = TeX("RH.crit=qf((1-alpha),n1-1,n2-1)", output = "character"), 
           parse = TRUE,
           size = 5, na.rm = TRUE)+
  annotate("segment", x = 3.78, xend = 3.78, y = 0.33, yend = 0.2, 
           linewidth=2, alpha=0.6, arrow=arrow())+
  annotate(geom="text", x = 10, y = 0.3,
           hjust=0,
           label = TeX("beta=pf((RH.crit),n1-1,n2-1)", output = "character"), 
           parse = TRUE,
           size = 5, na.rm = TRUE)+
  annotate("segment", x = 10, xend = 3.5, y = 0.3, yend = 0.1, 
           linewidth=2, alpha=0.6, arrow=arrow())+
  annotate("segment", x = 26.01, xend = 26.01, y = 0, yend = 0.6, 
           linewidth=2, alpha=0.6, color="red")+
  annotate(geom="text", x = 26, y = 0.62,
           hjust=0,
           label = TeX("F=26", output = "character"), 
           parse = TRUE,
           size = 5, na.rm = TRUE)+
  theme_bw()
  


